# Android java run activity in background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I am creating a notification and I add "addAction" to my notification.
I want to when I click on the "addAction", the notification remove and run another one code.
How I can do this?

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
.........
 .addAction(R.drawable.eye, "View", pi)
```

I want to run Activity.class in background, I mean to that this activity doenst open but the code in this activity run.
How I can do this?

Comment: you can not be serious...

Comment: To run something in the background, you should make a Service and not an Activity.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run code in background, You have to create a **service**

ex

service code

```
package com.javatechig.serviceexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class HelloService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "HelloService";

    private boolean isRunning  = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");

        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

        //Creating new thread for my service
        //Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                //Your logic that service will perform will be placed here
                //In this example we are just looping and waits for 1000 milliseconds in each loop.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    if(isRunning){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Service running");
                    }
                }

                //Stop service once it finishes its task
                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        isRunning = false;

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.javatechig.serviceexample" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--Service declared in manifest -->
        <service android:name=".HelloService"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

To start the servcie , add below code to the activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
startService(intent);
```